# I'm level two, with enough "level ups" to get to around 14~ ish, how should I maximise my 5 level trains?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm too used to played Oblivion where I would not sleep in order to get 5 skill trains per level up. I forgot to do it on my first level up but now I'm level 2 and can train up to level 14.

Are you still able to do this in Skyrim, where you train five times, then level up, then train five times?

Comment: You are asking two completely separate questions here. I answered the first and I'm removing the second from your question. You should ask it as a separate question, but I'll give you a hint: Train skills by using them.

Comment: @Strix: you're misreading the question. He wants to pay for training. At a trainer. Which can be done 5x per level.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Then manswer is invalid (and thus deleted), but he was still asking 2 unrelated questions.

Answer (score 7):

You can't 'bank levels'  like this. Once you hit that 'level up' button you must take all 14 levels at once.

Sorry, but you've blown 60 opportunities to train.

FYI: You'd have a lot more gold if you'd leveled up a few times as foes would have dropped better loot. This makes training more affordable, even for less kleptomaniacally inclined character archetypes.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but possibly you can since it appears that it's only the UI (not game logic) that prevents you from backing out. Someone adventurous could try this: save (this is your backup!), do one level-up, open the console while in the level-up screen and type `save putanamehere` (to save your game), then `qqq` to force-quit the game. Then start up Skyrim again, load the save made from the console, and check what level you are. Do it a few times to ensure that it doesn't break levelling up, and let us know if it works. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can back out on consoles if you are fast enough hitting cancel after choosing your stat (spam the cancel button as you are are accepting the stat choice)

On PC, if you spam 'Escape' at the same point you don't get out completely, but you do close the skill menu, which enables you to back out completely on on your next stat choice, assuming you are again fast enough spamming.

So on PC you can get half your saved up levels at least.

Comment: Thanks for posting this sKary, you just saved me from having to jump back 6 game hours! Confirmed on xbox360

Answer (score 1):

You can save up your levels, yes. However, you cannot 'back out' from what I can tell if you have multiple levels to spend. So no, you can't do the 5 trains between accepting level ups if you have multiple levels ready. But you CAN save your levels, if you want to play lower difficulty monsters all day and crap gear. You'll just miss out on perks and the bonuses to health/magic/stam you can do.

As for sneaking, yes. You can. However, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-you-sneak-well-with-heavy-armor-compared-to-light-or-is-there-no-difference/36082#36082) for more details on how to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone on PC if you find yourself leveling too fast download this mod: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10037/?
It adds new perks and such but im pretty sure there are options to disable this (check the mod description) you can go into the ingame settings for the mod and lower the rate of exp you get **(This can be custom set for each skill if you want)**

Then if you want to put you level down (Say you where level 40 but you leveled up too much to fast and wanted to go down)

1. Bring up the console with the Tilde key (Underneath ESC and above TAB)
2. type player.setlevel 20 (the number 20 is where you put the Level Number in, this can
   be anything)
3. Press Enter

(Note you can also set skill level the same way, just replace the word level with skill. also note that Speech is Speechcraft and Bow skill is Marksman)
e.g player.setskill marksman 100

If you minimized your game screen to check out a fix and you dont want to get a black screen when you reopen the window just open the window then press ALT+TAB twice, now wait for the black screen to disappear (this is will either be instant or if you have many graphical enhancements like an enb it will take longer, be patient). So now you can look up console commands in peace :)
The only flaw in this (if you would call it one) is that you keep any perk points that you gained, (for example if you went from level 1 to level 5 and got 4 perk points, then set the level back to 1, you would still have the 4 perk points) essentially you can now add perk points for really cheap if you have patience.